# Make generated content stay on page for multiple user communication?

Tags: javascript, php, session-cookies, forum

Specifically the addElement and addText functions for this application. 
I'd like for multiple users to be reading each other's posts. 
I've also implemented image uploading with the getfile.php page attached.

```
     <?php 
    $pgHeading="Pyramid Image Board - A frontier of free speech"; 
    $pgDesc="An image board made from the ground up by an unqualified 
    programmer.";            
    $pgKeywords="Chan, Image Board, Trade media, Internet Talk"; 
    ?>
    <html>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pgDesc ?>"></meta> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $pgKeywords ?>"></meta> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    </meta>      
    <body>
    <header>
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script>
  function addtext() {
  var newtext = document.myform.inputtext.value;
  document.myform.outputtext.value += newtext;
    }

  function addElement() {

   var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');

   var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');

    var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value - 1) + 2;

    numi.value = num;

     var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

     var divIdName = 'Post#' + num + ":";

     newdiv.setAttribute('id', divIdName);

    newdiv.innerHTML = (divIdName) + document.myform.inputtext.value;
    ni.appendChild(newdiv);
     }
      </script>
      <style>

      #LL {
       position: relative;
       color: #00AABB;
       }

       div {
       margin: 0 auto;
       color: black;
      border-radius: 8px;
       background: linear-gradient(white, white, gray);
       padding-top: 0px;
       width: 600px;
       height: 55px;
        }

       #fs {
       margin: 0 auto;
       border-radius: 9px;
       width: 603px;
       background: linear-gradient(white, grey, white);

        }

        .clearfix {
         overflow: auto;
          }

          #textbox {
          height: 90px;
          width: 560px;
          border-radius: 6px;
          margin-left: 18px;
          }

          #post {
          border-radius: 7px;
          position: relative;
          left: 437px;
          color: black;
          }

           #inforce {
           position: fixed;
           top: 24px;
           left: 14px;
            }
            </style>

            </header>
           <fieldset id="fs">
           <input type="hidden" value="0" id="theValue" />
            <legend id=LL>. .<span id="inforce">.</span>
            </legend>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="getfile.php"  method="post" name="myform">
     <textarea id="textbox" type="text" size="50" name="inputtext" />
     </textarea>

 <input type="file" name="uploadFile">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="25000" />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
     <button class="btn btn-info" id="post" onClick="addtext()">
        <a value="Add New Text" href="javascript:;" onclick="addElement()">
  POST
   </a>
     </button>
    </fieldset>
      <span>
       <div id="myDiv">

         </div>
        </form>
        </span>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html



        //and here is the getfile.php// 

        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Process Uploaded File</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
        if ( move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadFile'] ['tmp_name'], 
        "/home/ubuntu/workspace/uploads/{$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name']}")  )
        {  print '<p> The file has been successfully uploaded </p>'; 
        header('Location:index.php');                    
              }
           else
             { 
        switch ($_FILES['uploadFile'] ['error'])
        {  case 1:
               print '<p> The file is bigger than this PHP installation    
                    allows</p>';    break;
        case 2:
               print '<p> The file is bigger than this form allows</p>';
               break;
        case 3:
               print '<p> Only part of the file was uploaded</p>';
               break;
        case 4:
               print '<p> No file was uploaded</p>';
               break;
                   }
                  }
              ?>
                 </body>
                  </html>
```

Comment: you need to mod the html file with php before serving, or do something dynamic

Comment: I've literally just started using php today and it's not really straight-forward